# create histograms for all categorical variable values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data like the example data below, which has columns with categorical data like “var1” and “var2” below and then columns with continuous data.  What I would like to do is create histograms for every continuous variable by each value from the categorical columns.  I’ve done it in the example code below just for var1=‘Y’, but I’d like to do it for var1=’N’, and each of the var2 values.  Is there some simple way to do this, besides coding it over and over again by hand or turning it in to a function?

Example data:

```
var1=['Y','N','Y','Y','N','Y']
var2=['S','V','H','S','V','H']
cont1=[1,3,4,5,2,7]
cont2=[4,3,4,5,5,7]
cont3=[3,7,4,5,2,1]

data={'var1':var1,'var2':var2,'cont1':cont1,'cont2':cont2,'cont3':cont3}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Code:

```
df[df['var1']=='Y'].hist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `by` argument in `pandas.DataFrame.hist()`:

If you want to see one continuous variable for every seen combination of `var1` and `var2`:

```
df.hist(column='cont1', by=['var1','var2'])
```

[image]

If you want to see all the continuous variables in different colors on the same plot for every combination of `var1` and `var`:

```
df.hist(by=['var1', 'var2'])
```

[image]

You can also do the `by` argument with each categorical column alone if you would prefer to view the data that way:

```
df.hist(by='var1')
```

[image]

```
df.hist(by='var2')
```

[image]

Obviously with your sample data they are little too simplistic to see, but I think if you apply that syntax to your data you should be able to get what you seek.

EDIT:
If you want to easily go through a listing of columns you can use it in a list comprehension and utilize the returned array of axis as you need or use it in a for loop with more complex manipulation of the axis into a figure of your desired output.

```
varsToLoop = ['var1','var2']
[df.hist(by=x) for x in varsToLoop]
```

[image]

Comment: @jweeder thanks for getting back to me so quickly.  That's pretty close to what I was looking for.  I think I'll still have to write a function to loop through var1, var2 with "by", but that's pretty helpful

Comment: @user3476463 keep in mind that the df.hist() acutally returns an array of axis with the length equal to the number of unique responses in the var1 or var2.  So you could generate the axis with a list comprehension as in my most recent edit and use as you need.  May be easier than writing out a loop/function just for that case.